# Whats the real place on Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow to ask about Windows scripts?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need a script that will traverse the folder structure starting from F:\FolderName and delete a Build folder if found in any of the `FolderName`'s subfolders.

If it were for Linux, I'd ask on AskUbuntu. Since it's for Windows 7, I got no real idea where to ask.

Comment: Note that in general such a script, even with `#/bin/sh` in front of it, would be on topic in SU (as well as anywhere else it fits). There's some overlap.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely you want [Super User](http://superuser.com). I suspect [superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch) or [superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch-file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch-file). Your question might even already be answered.

Comment: You might find such scripts on StackOverflow as well but asking for such script would be off-topic.